# Using OpenCV to find people who wear a certain hat

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I would like to use computer vision to do the following:

A camera is mounted outside a building, capturing a videostream of the street below. The camera is installed approximately 5-6 meters above the street.

Whenever a person wearing a certain kind of hat(white, round) is captured by the camera, an event should be triggered.

Which algorithm should I look into to implement this kind of behavior ?

Is this best achieved through training the algorithm with sample data or is there another way to tell it to look for this type of hat ?

Also, how do I use multiple frames of video to increase the quality of detection ?

[image: The beautiful people wearing white round hats]

Edit: Added a picture of the hat

Comment: Well, thanks for the immediate downvote. Care to explain why?

Comment: The reason for the immediate downvote (not by me) may be that "Computer vision" is not a software package you install and then have some built-in function magically solve your problem. Nor is your problem likely to be solved by one simple algorithm. To be fair, OpenCV seems to lead people to believe this kind of stuff. I would suggest that you do some initial reading on Vision first and ask more specifically later. To be a bit more constructive, here is an excellent overview read: http://szeliski.org/Book/

Comment: @DCS, thanks for your answer. I understand there is no easy "just use this algorithm/package and you're set" kind of answer. However, I was hoping for a pointer in the right direction for this particular task. I've seen OpenCV used by artists who knew just enough about CV (and programming) to make their project work. I think it is safe to assume that I do not need to be a CV specialist to start playing with it ?

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to play with OpenCV, but in order to solve a real-world problem with it you do need quite some expertise. A visual artist using OpenCV is probably aiming for something that looks cool. But you want to solve a real Vision problem, and this is a difficult task, and requires some reading of theory on your side. To give you some pointers: If you are very lucky you can get away with blob detection and color classification (identify a white blob), but this is almost certainly too simplistic. Can you post an image showing the scene you want to analyze?

Comment: @DCS : Thank you, I posted the picture. This would describe a method of blob detection, right ? http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/  I could try to match based on color, size, movement at human speed. Is it worth also researching techniques that require training like http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html or is this something for other domains?

Comment: Updated link: http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we do everything in comments I will start an answer here.

The first [link](http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/) you posted describes a simple color-based detection. You can try that, but it will fail if there are other pixel clusters of similar color in the image. Your idea of  combining it with tracking is good: Identify clusters, build trajectories over several images, and only accept plausible trajectories as a hit. For robust tracking you may want to look into [Kalman filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). A problem you will most likely encounter is that a "white" hat will hardly be "white" in the images your camera delivers.

The second [link](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) you refer to - boosted Classifiers Based on Haar-like Features - is for detection of more complex objects. It probably won't help you find white blobs. Invest your time and energy in learning about tracking.

I'm happy to repeat myself here: "Solving a computer vision problem" is not something like "sorting an array". OpenCV is not the C++ Standard Library. You can use an `std::map` without knowing anything about a red-black tree. But (IMHO) you can't use Vision APIs without knowing a good deal of the math and [theory](http://szeliski.org/Book/). Working solutions Computer Vision are typically heavily tuned towards the specific problem scenario. Sorry if that sounds pedantic, but it explains why your question got beaten.

Comment: This is a very good answer, exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you for the pointer to Kalman filtering.